# Is it possible to host a RADIUS server on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, radius, nps, windows-ias-server

Is it possible to host a RADIUS server on **Windows 7**.

I am trying to use this as an authenticating server for my Routers. A third-party application is fine, however maybe if its possible it can use IAS or NPS?

I tried to enable IAS through the Windows 7 "Turn Windows features on or off", However I couldn't find it anywhere so maybe its not available in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

Internet Authentication Service (IAS) is part of Windows Server operating systems and is not available for desktop editions. As IAS stores its authentication information on Active Directory, you would need to have an AD environment anyway, thus already having Windows Servers you could use for this role, too.

Instead, you could use [FreeRADIUS](https://freeradius.org/) Server, ([.net](http://freeradius.net/) for Windows binary). It can store its authentication information e.g. on an SQL database.

Comment: Is WinRADIUS a free software? Because when I downloaded and tried to install the 64-bit Binary version from winradius.eu, it asks for a registration code and even if it is paid, I can't find where to purchase it. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be FreeRADIUS binary for Windows without third party products, too. Just modified my answer accordingly.